# How to delete all directories with a particular name?

Tags: directory, delete

Under a directory, I have a bunch of directories named `Debug`. How do I delete all the `Debug` directories?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear --- under the directory `dir_a` you can have only one directory named `Debug`. Or are you saying that you have `dir_a/Debug`, `dir_a/dir_b/Debug`, `dir_a/dir_c/Debug` and so on?

You can list all directory named *exactly* `Debug` under the directory `dir_a` with:

```
cd dir_a   # or whatever you need to go there
find . -type d -name Debug
```

this will list all the directories named `Debug` under the current directory. To delete them (double check, this **IS NOT UNDOABLE**):

```
find . -depth -type d -name Debug -exec rm -r {} \;
```

`-depth` will list `Debug/Debug/` before `Debug/` to avoid errors.

In detail:

1. `find . -type d -name Debug` will search all directory under the current one (`.`) for entries which are both directory (`-type d`) and have the name "Debug" (`-name Debug`).
2. The added `-depth` flag make the search depth-first (it means that "deeper" matches are found before "shallow" ones).
3. `-exec ... \;` tells `find` to execute the command in `...` for each match. (The semicolon is quoted because otherwise the shell will interpret it).
4. In the command `...` above, the special symbol `{}` is substituted by the current match.

So in plain English it is: find every directory under this one which name is "Debug", depth first, and for each one execute the command `rm -r` followed by the full name of the directory.

Comment: If you use GNU find's `-delete` option, does that remove the need for `-depth`?

Comment: @terdon thought about it (the man page says that `-delete` implies `-depth`), but it protests about directories not empty... that was the reason to use the `rm -r` things.

Comment: In "rm -r {} \;" command, what does "{} \;" option mean?  Try to google  rm linux command, but find none examples for that option.   Should I find them in examples of other commands?

Comment: @sontra, You will find the description of `{}` and `\;` in the `find` manual, not `rm`. I added some detailed info.